# How to open a file with Visual Studio Code from within a PowerShell console?

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I try to open a file in Visual Studio Code from within a PowerShell console. In other words I want to emulate the option of **Open with** when right clicking a file to open it with the non-default application, but from the PowerShell command line. I found a Stack Overflow question with this solution:

```
Visual studio code D:\testfolder\index.html
```

But it does not work. Are there any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: I believe all you need to do is say `code D:\testfolder\index.html`, does this not work? In order to open an item in another application, usually you need to find that applications EXE, and pass the file you want to open to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use -n flag if you have an existing vs code window open and you want to open the file in new seperate window.
so the command will be

```
code D:\testfolder\index.html -n
```

or

```
code -n D:\testfolder\index.html
```